# Leak when using autorelease?

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks

Even though I release the results object using autorelease, the Leak tool it is showing 100% leak in leak instrument.

```
ResultsViewController *results = [[[ResultsViewController alloc]initWithNibName:
                                @"ResultsViewController1" bundle:nil] autorelease];
[results getscore:(int)score:(int)skippedwords:(int)crtwords];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:results animated:YES];
```

Comment: I'm not sure that would even compile. What's that second line do? But if we ignore that, your code is fine. Which means the leak (if there is one) is elsewhere.

Comment: This code is fine. Maybe Instruments show you a leak because you have a leak in ResultsViewController

Comment: from second line i am passing values to the resultsviewcontroller

Comment: Yes u are correct there is leak in Results view Controller also

Comment: What's the object name instruments saying the leaking is? That's the object you need to take a close look. I think your problem is in your Results ViewController.

Answer (score 0):

In "`Instruments`" it always show you the autoreleased objects as "leaks"

Do one thing alloc/release "`results`" by yourself. Never ever use "`Autorelease`" until unless you have to return the object to other class or method.

```
ResultsViewController *results = [[ResultsViewController alloc]initWithNibName: @"ResultsViewController1" bundle:nil];

[results getscore:score :skippedwords :crtwords];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:results animated:YES]; 

[results release];
```

Because you have already pushed this controller to navigation controller so you don't need its instance anymore. Happy Coding ;)

Comment: You'll have an Exc_Bad_Access in this code because you have two release!

Comment: actually that was by mistake! I have already corrected that :)

Comment: there is nothing wrong with using autorelease in the way it was used in the question. Pre ARC there was a good argument that doing that was better overall than calling release, since it was less prone to manual error